Exercise 6, Hoffman and Kunze Ch1.

prove that if two homogenous systems of linear equations in two unknowns share the same solution, then they are equivalent

Here is my idea:
(1) Name the systems $A$ and $B$. Let $A_1$ be a linear combination of $A$. If $(s_{11} , s_{12})$ is a solution of $A$, then $(s_{11} , s_{12})$ is a solution of $A_1$
(2) Since $A$ and $B$ share the same solutions, then $(s_{11} , s_{12})$ must also be a solution of $B$. If $B_1$ is a linear combination of $B$, then $(s_{11} , s_{12})$ must also be a solution of $B_1$.
(3) Since $A$ and $B$ are homogenous, any linear combination $A_1$ of $A$ and $B_1$ of $B$ must obviously be homogenous also.
(4) Now let $c$ be any equation in $A$. Since the pair $(s_{11} , s_{12})$ is a solution of the entire system $A$, it must necessarily be a solution of its part $c$. Now apply the same reasoning in (2)-(3) and it follows that $c$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $B$
(5) Since $c$ was arbitrary, any equation in $A$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $B$. Analogously, any equation in $B$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $A$. Therefore, $A$ and $B$ are equivalent
I think my reasoning is sound, but the real issue lies in (4). Sure, $c$ can be equated with a corresponding linear combination of $B$ with $0$. But that doesn't gaurantee that there exists a solution $(n_1, n_2)$ for the system that will arise for which the coefficients will match and only then will $c$ can truly be expressed as such a linear combination of $B$

"Now apply the same reasoning in (2)-(3) and it follows that $c$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $B$"? "Sure, $c$ can be equated with a corresponding linear combination of $B$ with $0$"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Equivalence

Idk what i was thinking haha, this is my very first exposure to linear alg. Ill delete the post or the mod will do it
